# Print Preview in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, print-preview

I am using Oracle SQL Developer ver 3.0.04 and realizing that the "Print Preview" menu entry is greyed out. I cannot set any "Print Area" either.

It is a standard installaton on Windows XP and I have not done any special setting except user language JVM option. I have been using this tool quit long but I have never printed something from this tool - i.e., the "Print Preview" function does not work from the very beginning probably.

Any hint?